# firebase authentication after login app automatically recent Minimized

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

firebase authentication after login success app automatically minimize.

**android studio error logcat here.**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 15474
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a FirebaseFirestore object.
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a FirebaseFirestore object.
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(FirebaseFirestore.java:267)
> at com.myapp.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

```
     final String signInUsername = username.getText().toString().trim().concat(USER_EMAIL_SUFFIX);
    String signInPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(signInUsername,signInPassword).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("extras",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            DSLog log = new DSLog(System.currentTimeMillis(),signInUsername, LOGGED_IN);
            editor.putLong("time",log.getTimestamp());
            editor.apply();
            logsCollectionRef.document(log.getTimestamp()+"").set(log).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Intent toEventList = new Intent(com.myapp.myapp.LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(toEventList);
                        unfadeLoginBox();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(com.myapp.myapp.LoginActivity.this,"Could not Log In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            unfadeLoginBox();
            Toast.makeText(com.myapp.myapp.LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `logsCollectionRef` defined?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the exception, this problem is possibly occuring due to FirebaseFirestore.

> FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a FirebaseFirestore object

Also check the code at this line since the exception is pointing out to here

> (FirebaseFirestore.java:267) at com.myapp.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)

Without the full code it's difficult to trace out the issue. Please add more code especially which is pointed out by the exception.